# Evaluating an integral involving $xe^{-x^2 / 2}$ and a similar infinite series.

Tags: integration

**Problem** Evaluate the following definite integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \left(x - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^5}{2\cdot 4} - \frac{x^7}{2\cdot4\cdot 6} + \cdot \cdot \cdot \right) \left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{x^4}{2^2 \cdot 4^2 } +\frac{x^6}{2^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 6^2 } + \cdot \cdot \cdot \right) $$

I figured the first term in the expansion is just equal to

$$ xe^{-x^2 / 2} = x\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{(2\cdot 2)(2\cdot 1)} - \frac{x^6}{(3\cdot 2)(2\cdot 2)(2 \cdot 1)} + \cdot \cdot \cdot  \right)$$

Thus the integral is reduced to

$$\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2 / 2} \left(1 + \frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{x^4}{2^2 \cdot 4^2 } +\frac{x^6}{2^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 6^2 } + \cdot \cdot \cdot \right) $$

A similar expression for the second term does not seem plausible to me. Any hints would be appreciated.

Attempting to integrate term by term, we obtain the series.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^{n} e^{-t}}{2^n (n!)^2}$$

We may integrate each term in the series by parts, to obtain the following

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t)^{n} e^{-t}}{2^n (n!)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-e^{-t}}{2^n (n!)} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac{t^{n-i}}{(n-i)!} |_{0}^{\infty} \right)  $$

However I do not know how to proceed, nor do I think this approach is correct since the problem was given in an high school exam.

Comment: The second term is some Bessel function, but you need not know it - just try termwise integration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may integrate term by term. Call the integral in question $I$ and let $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. It is an easy exercise in using Stein's Lemma to show $$E|X^{2p+1}| = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(2p)!!$$ Thus $$\frac{I}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{[(2p)!!]^2}E|X^{2p+1}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2p)!!} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(1/2)^n}{n!} = \sqrt{\frac{e}{2\pi}}$$

Comment: The answer given is $1$, however what does $(2p)!!$ mean here?

Comment: $$(2p)!! = 2p\cdot (2p-2) \cdot (2p-4) \cdot \dots \cdot 2$$

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal all the steps look okay to me, so maybe your answer key is wrong

Comment: I found the source of the problem, it appears to be PUTNAM 1997 A3. The answer given is same as yours, so quite possibly the key is incorrect.